# Mosquitto on Ubuntu not working with Letsencypt Certificate

Tags: ubuntu, mqtt, mosquitto

Error :

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-37-161:~$ sudo systemctl status mosquitto.service
× mosquitto.service - Mosquitto MQTT Broker
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mosquitto.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2023-01-02 18:36:02 UTC; 10min ago
       Docs: man:mosquitto.conf(5)
             man:mosquitto(8)
    Process: 7652 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -m 740 -p /var/log/mosquitto (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 7653 ExecStartPre=/bin/chown mosquitto /var/log/mosquitto (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 7654 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -m 740 -p /run/mosquitto (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 7655 ExecStartPre=/bin/chown mosquitto /run/mosquitto (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 7656 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 7656 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 14ms

Jan 02 18:36:02 ip-172-31-37-161 systemd[1]: mosquitto.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 02 18:36:02 ip-172-31-37-161 systemd[1]: mosquitto.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 02 18:36:02 ip-172-31-37-161 systemd[1]: Failed to start Mosquitto MQTT Broker.
Jan 02 18:36:02 ip-172-31-37-161 systemd[1]: mosquitto.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Jan 02 18:36:02 ip-172-31-37-161 systemd[1]: Stopped Mosquitto MQTT Broker.
Jan 02 18:36:02 ip-172-31-37-161 systemd[1]: mosquitto.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jan 02 18:36:02 ip-172-31-37-161 systemd[1]: mosquitto.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 02 18:36:02 ip-172-31-37-161 systemd[1]: Failed to start Mosquitto MQTT Broker.
```

My conf.d file :

```
allow_anonymous false

password_file /etc/mosquitto/passwd

listener 1883
#NON SECURE PORT

listener 1884
certfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/cert.pem
cafile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/chain.pem
keyfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem
```

If I comment or remove the last line : keyfile, then Mosquitto broker works fine and there is no error. Can anyone please help solve this problem. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure that the `mosquitto` user has read access to the certificate and key files.

By default the key files are only readable by the `root` user.

P.s. you should probably be using the`fullchain.pem` file instead of the `cert.pem` to ensure things work best.

Comment: Should I do it like this : 

listener 1884
cafile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem

And remove the other .pem entries? And use the same certificate in my embedded devices?

Comment: The `cafile` is only used to verify client certificates, it should not be using the letsencrypt certs at all (since they do not issue client certs). Remove `cafile` and change `certfile` to point to the `fullchain.pem`

Comment: Did that but when I try to run the subscribe command, it throws an error : ////
mosquitto_sub -h localhost -t "test" -u "USER" -P "PASS" --cert /etc/letsencrypt/live/sdomain/fullchain.pem
Error: Both certfile and keyfile must be provided if one of them is set.////

And if I add the keyfile also : ////

mosquitto_sub -h localhost -t "test" -u "USER" -P "PASS" --cert /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/fullchain.pem --key etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/privkey.pem
Error: Connection refused

Comment: At this time my default.conf file is this : /////
allow_anonymous false

password_file /etc/mosquitto/passwd

listener 1884
certfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/fullchain.pem

Comment: This is now 2 different questions, I think the original answer is why the broker failed to start. You now have a second question to do with client certificate authentication for which we do not have enough information to answer. Ask a NEW question giving ALL the details of how you are trying to connect clients to the broker. (You should probably not be using LetsEncrypt certificates to authenticate clients, because ANYBODY can get a LetsEncrypt certificate)

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will raise a new question. :)